# Routing traffic to several API Gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I would like to split my template with all the lambda functions into several templates for each domain (products, users etc). The lambdas are supposed to be accessed from an API. I cannot create a single API for these, CloudFormation arouses issues on that ApiEvents should be intruduced in the same template as the API itself. And it doesn't help if I nest the stacks. So my approach would be that each template has its own API from which the lambdas are accessible. But each API naturally has its own URL when CF deploys them.

The events for the serverless functions are described for each function as:

```
GetFoos:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    ...
    Events:
       GetFoos:
         Type: Api 
         Properties:
           Path: /foo
           Method: get
           RestApiId: 
             !Ref MyApi
```

Obviously I would like to access all the lambdas from the same base URL. So test.myproject.com/products would access functions in products template via its API and test.myproject.com/users would access functions in users teamplate via its API. How could this be done?

Can I user Elastic Load Balancer to route traffic to different APIs based on the requested path? Route53? Should I use AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName and AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping?

Or do I need a complete makeover for my project? That would be bad news since the project is near to the deadline. I just ran into the issue with over 200 resources per one template and something needs to be done. There are about 70 lambdas in my functions template but CF creates AWS::Lambda::Permission resources for each of these lambdas so Api can invoke them. Can this be done manually so that Api had only one Permission to access every lambda?

Comment: You can't use ALB in front of API gateway to my knowledge. Its targets can be IP address, instance-id or lambda only.

Comment: R53 can't direct traffic based on path (/products, /users), but you could create subdomains, products.test.myproject.com, users.tests.myproject.com.

Comment: Subdomains can't be done at this case. How can I link Gateway API paths and lambda functions without Events,then I could use only one Gateway API and put functions in multiple stacks, with Events I cannot do that.

Comment: You should be able to use ALB in front of your API Gateway. But it has to be public ALB i.e. it endpoint has to be public